# Multi-line PCRE w\ lookahead, issue counting matches

Tags: regex, perl, optimization, pcre

I am trying to perform a regex that matches if both the word cat AND dog are in the regex in any order with multi-line support

```
matches

cat asdjfaldsfj dog
####
does NOT match

cat adfasdf8989
####
matches

dog adlsjf88989 cat
####
matches

cat asdf8a89sdf8
a sdf asd f ads f ads fasdf
dog  a dsf ads fads f
asdfadsfadsf
```

The regex I'm using is pretty simple

```
/^(?=.*\bcat\b)(?=.*\bdog\b).*$/gs
```

The problem is that this only finds the first occurrence since it is greedy.  I really want the following to count two matches but it only matches once

```
cat asdf8a89sdf8
a sdf asd f ads f ads fasdf
dog  a dsf ads fads f
asdfadsfadsf
cat asdf8a89sdf8
a sdf asd f ads f ads fasdf
dog  a dsf ads fads f
asdfadsfadsf
```

Even without the second set of cat STUFF dog STUFF the regex still matches until the end.

I'm using regex101.com to test.

Comment: Is this Perl or PCRE? You tagged both, said PCRE, but use a Perl match operator.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem isn't that you're using greedy quantifiers; it's that you're using using the `^` anchor along with lookahead and `.*`. The pattern will have no choice but to match either everything or nothing.

Instead, just drop the lookahead approach and match `cat` and `dog` with anything in between, or the other way around:

`/cat.*?dog|dog.*?cat/gs`

In this case, you actually do need to specify lazy quantifiers with `?`, or else it will grab all matches as one match like you feared.

https://regex101.com/r/nv9Nj7/1

Comment: "cat" and "dog" was an example.  Let's say I wanted to find "cat","dog","bird","fish" in any order.  Then I would have to either do the lookahead or a ton of permutations.

Comment: Ah, thought you only had a maximum of two. In that case yeah, this solution would not be very scalable.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion, but perhaps this is more readable than a complex regex

```
use List::MoreUtils 'all';

my @things = qw( cat dog bird fish );

for my $line ( @lines ) {
    if ( all { $line =~ / \b $_ \b /x } @things ) {
        # DO STUFF
    }
}
```

The `all` function is part of [List::MoreUtils](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils), but also available in [List::AllUtils](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::AllUtils) and [List::SomeUtils](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::SomeUtils)

This implementation relies on you processing your string line by line, so you might do something like `for my line ( split(/\n/, $string) ) { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

CAustin's answer can be simplified to:

```
/(cat|dog).*?(?!\1)(?:cat|dog)/gs
```

which is easier to expand to more strings.  With 4 strings:

```
/(cat|dog|bird|fish).*?(?!\1)(cat|dog|bird|fish).*?(?!\1|\2)(cat|dog|bird|fish).*?(?!\1|\2|\3)(?:cat|dog|bird|fish)/gs
```

and restricting some useless backtracking:

```
/(cat|dog|bird|fish)(?>.*?(?!\1)(cat|dog|bird|fish))(?>.*?(?!\1|\2)(cat|dog|bird|fish))(?>.*?(?!\1|\2|\3)(?:cat|dog|bird|fish))/gs
```